# Getting SAML response with Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge, saml

I am currently using Selenium to automate a browser process where I have to extract the SAML response out of a webpage.

To achieve this I'm using the `.pageSource` method from selenium  however this returns the html and not the payload shown in the network console tab from my browser dev tools ( see screenshot).

Does anyone know how I can capture the SAML Response payload with selenium?

```
function New-SAMLInteractive{
   

    [CmdletBinding()]

       param(

             [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]

             [string] $LoginIDP

       )

    Begin{ 

        $RegEx = '(?i)name="SAMLResponse"(?: type="hidden")? value=\"(.*?)\"(?:.*)?\/>'

        Import-Module -Name 'U:\Selenium\Selenium\3.0.1\Selenium.psd1'

    }

    Process{

        $Driver = Start-SeEdge -Quiet

        Enter-SeUrl $LoginIDP -Driver $Driver          

         Do {

                    Write-Host "Check SAMLRespons"

                    $html = $Driver.PageSource

                    if ($html -match "SAMLResponse"){
                      
                        if ($html -match $RegEx){
         
                        $Script:SAMLResponse = $(($Matches[1] -replace '&#x2b;', '+') -replace '&#x3d;', '=')

                        Write-Output $Script:SAMLResponse

                        $SAML=True

                        write-host 'SAML Found!!!'

                }

            }
       

        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1

        }

        Until ($SAML -eq ($True))

        Write-Host "Loop Ended" 

       }               

  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're using PowerShell Selenium. I'm afraid you cannot access such kind of data using PowerShell, at least it does not support that natively. However, **Selenium 4** has added a new support for devtools so that you can access the response and request directly. Check the [doc](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/bidirectional/bidi_api/) for more information, but you may have to try other languages.